# why does dd calculated speed uses k=1000. Is it a bug?

Tags: linux

Here is an output from my `dd if=/dev/st0 of=/dev/null bs=512k`

```
195401+12251 records in
195401+12251 records out
104857600000 bytes (105 GB) copied, 877.728 seconds, 119 MB/s
```

If we take MB = 1024 * 1024 we will get the following speed:

```
104857600000 / 877.728 / 1024 / 1024 = 113.9305115024244 = 114 MB/s
```

The output, however, suggests that MB is 1000 * 1000 instead, and here is proof:

```
104857600000 / 877.728 / 1000 / 1000 = 119.4648000291662 = 119 MB/s
```

Is it a bug or what?!

Comment: This is a megabyte vs mebibyte thing. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - Chris, I got that, but since when dd uses metric version?! I remember times when 1MB of HD was '1024 * 1024'. Then WD came in, and it was '1000 * 1024'. Now dd uses '1000 * 1000'?!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, but if you read the [dd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd), the small `k` might be accepted as an abbreviation for `kB`, which means 1000 bytes.  So it may be outputting the statistics using the same divisor as you indicated with the `bs=` parameter.

Comment: Nice try, but then shouldn't it print out Mb instead of MB? I have just tried default block size (512b) and it keeps using 1000*1000 as Mb. I am big time disappointed (if it makes any sense) that it uses 1000 instead of 1024. Although my tools will all of a sudden be faster, but that is NOT what I expected at all.